# Finding Element On WebForm_OnSubmit()

Tags: javascript

I want the page to scroll to a control when the associated requiredfieldvalidator (ASP.Net) has been triggered. I have tested all the code pieces individually and they all work fine. However, when I combine them into WebForm_OnSubmit() I am unable to find the controltovalidate. The code only finds some object that always has these properties:

Validators,__browserLink_sourceMapping

I have no idea what this means or why it's happening. Can anyone point me to the mistake in the code?

I have tried finding the controltovalidate using both JS and jQuery, but they both yield the same object.

Here's the code

```
function WebForm_OnSubmit() { 
if (typeof (ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) { 
   for (var i in Page_Validators) {

      //Verify it's the correct validation group & it's a triggered validation ctrl
      try { 
           if (Page_Validators[i].validationGroup == "MyValidationGrp" && !Page_Validators[i].isvalid) { 

//I've used these lines just to verify it's finding the correct control ID value before trying to get the control. Both this and the jQuery below yield the same result
//var ControlToScrollToId = Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate; 
//var ControlToScrollTo = document.getElementById(ControlToScrollToId);

//I've used this code to look at the properties of the object:
//alert(ControlToScrollToId + " properties: " + Object.getOwnPropertyNames(ControlToScrollTo));

                    var control = $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate);

var top = control.offset().top;
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: top - 10 }, 800);
control.focus();
break;
}
} catch (e)
{ 
console.error("Failed to scroll to validating control." + e.message);
break;
}
}
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The code ends up always scrolling to the top of the page because the value of 'top' is always zero. That's why I went backwards to check the object and its properties and that's when I got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root Cause: The problem appears to be related to the fact that I am using some controls which have a class of "d-none" (Bootstrap 4x). The code behaves as I've noted above when that class is present. However, if I change the class to "invisible" everything works fine. I would still like to know if that's the only "solution" of it there's a better way to do this.

Oh, I am not using hidden fields because the ASP.net validators won't work with that.